# Create BAT File To Delete or Remove A Specific Line From Host File

Tags: batch-file

I am new here. I need help creating a BAT File than can remove a specific line from host file. Sorry, I am not a coder but somehow able to understand. I have downloaded a script from different sites and made a slight modification and compiled to suite my specific need. For the overview of my compiled scripts it will do the following:

1. Upon opening the script first it will ask for your name. I will use this later to log my activity in my host file.
2. It will ask you what you would like to do and there are three choices. Add new, Delete, and exit.
3. When you enter add new, it will ask you to enter a domain name next the IP
   and when you proceed, it will do its job, inserting new line to host file flushing the DNS and making a copy in text file.
4. When I choose to delete a line, the process is still the same and the only difference is that it gets an error "Find parameter format not correct". I could not figure it out.

Here's my code:

```
@echo off
echo.
title Host File Editor
:start
cls
echo.
echo What do you want to do?
echo.
echo 1. Add New Entry
echo 2. Delete Entry
echo 3. Exit
echo.
set /p where=
echo.
if %where% equ 1 goto add_new
if %where% equ 2 goto del_entry
if %where% equ 3 goto rejected
cls

:add_new
cls
echo.
echo Enter Domain Name
echo.
set /p domain=Domain Name:
cls
echo.
echo Enter Domain IP Address
echo.
set /p ip=IP Address:
echo New entry (%ip% %domain%) will be added to Host File
echo.
pause
cls
goto :accepted

:--------------------------------------------

:REJECTED
cls
ECHO Your HOSTS file was left unchanged.
ECHO Finished.
echo.
pause
GOTO EOF


:ACCEPTED
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
::Create your list of host domains
set LIST=(%domain%)
::Set the ip of the domains you set in the list above
set %domain%=%ip%
:: deletes the parentheses from LIST
set _list=%LIST:~1,-1%
::ECHO %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts > host.txt
for  %%G in (%_list%) do (
set  _name=%%G
set  _value=!%%G!
SET NEWLINE=^& echo.
ECHO Carrying out requested modifications to your HOSTS file
::strip out this specific line and store in tmp file
type %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts | findstr /v !_name! > host.txt
::re-add the line to it
ECHO %NEWLINE%^!_value! !_name!>>host.txt
::overwrite host file
copy /b/v/y tmp.txt %WINDIR%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts

)
ipconfig /flushdns
ECHO.
pause
ECHO New entry successfully added!
ECHO.
goto :start

;-------Delete Entry--------------------------------------

:del_entry
cls
echo.
echo Enter Domain Name
echo.
set /p domain=Domain Name:
cls
echo.
echo Enter Domain IP Address
echo.
set /p ip=IP Address:
echo %ip% %domain% will be removed from Host File
echo %ip% %domain%>ip.txt
echo.
pause
cls

@echo off
FOR /F "delims=^n tokens=*" %%a IN (%ip% %domain%) do call :func "%%a"

:func
set line=%1
set hf=%windir%\system32\drivers\etc\hosts
find /v %line% < %hf% >> newhosts
rename newhosts hosts
copy /a /y hosts %hf%
pause
goto start
```

Little help really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: This script is really not good coded and should be completely rewritten. I would make the first change already on second line by removing it. `start` is an internal command of `cmd.exe`. So this string can, but should not be used as a label. `choice` is better for a menu than `set /p`. `where` is an external command (executable in directory `%SystemRoot%\System32`). It is possible to use an environment variable with name `where`, but it should not be done. [ECHO. FAILS to give text or blank line - Instead use ECHO/](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=774)

Comment: The batch file does not take [Windows File System Redirector](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/WinProg64/file-system-redirector) into account and so the batch file fails completely on being executed on 64-bit Windows in a 32-bit environment because on 64-bit Windows there is only `%SystemRoot%\System32\drivers\etc\hosts,` but there is no `%SystemRoot%\SysWOW64\drivers\etc` at all.

Comment: Hi, thank you for a quick response. I will try it again. Thanks.